# how to read registry string value from batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to read registry string value, from bat file, and then assing the readed value to variable. 
I tried the following :

```
FOR  %%a in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\MathWorks\MATLAB\7.10 /v MATLABROOT') DO set MATLAB=%%a
echo %MATLAB%
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the value of a registry key from within a batch script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the name of the value (baz in this case) does not contain spaces you can do something like

```
FOR /F "skip=4 tokens=2,*" %%A IN ('REG.exe query "HKLM\software\foo\bar" /v "baz"') DO set "MATLABROOT=%%B"
```

If the name is dynamic and only known at run time, you would have to use tokens=* and parse %%A looking for "REG_" so you know where the data starts...

Comment: Pretty sure that'll break horribly if there are spaces in the path.

Comment: @CraigRinger: 2,* means %%B turns into the rest of the line. A bigger problem is things like skip=4 because it depends on the OS version etc. Doing this sort of thing in a batch file is going to be horrible no matter what you do...

Comment: Weird, isn't it. You'd think that "get a registry value into a variable" would be one of the most common needs in a batch file.

Answer (score 3):

`reg` prints out way more than just the very value you're interested in. As far as I can see, giving the `skip=2` and `tokens=3` option to `for` might work.

Might need to get a little more elaborate than that, though, if there are more spaces than anticipated.