# Batch file to find list of installed browsers

Tags: batch-file

I need to check for the available browsers in any Windows system by running a .bat file. The batch file should be able to check if Firefox and Chrome or any other browser is installed in system. Otherwise I want to open the default browser.

```
if exist "C:\Program Files(x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" start firefox.exe
```

This is a way to do this, but it won't work if the installation is done in some other location.

Comment: I guess you could work with registry values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184738/how-to-read-registry-string-value-from-batch-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet` key.  It lists the web browser clients that have registered themselves on the system and provides which one is the default and where to find each of them on the system.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd203067(v=vs.85).aspx for more details.

#### Example:

Here is just an example I threw together to illustrate how to use the information.  Adjust as you need it or based upon your requirements.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:Menu
echo 32-bit
set "Count=1"
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet" /ve 2^>nul') do set "Default=%%B"
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet" 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%~nxA"=="%Default%" (
        echo !Count!. %%~nA [Default]
    ) else (
        echo !Count!. %%~nA
    )
    set /a "Count+=1"
)
echo.
echo 64-bit if 32-bit above, else 32-bit
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet" /ve 2^>nul') do set "Default=%%B"
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet" 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%~nxA"=="%Default%" (
        echo !Count!. %%~nA [Default]
    ) else (
        echo !Count!. %%~nA
    )
    set /a "Count+=1"
)
echo.
:Input
set "Input="
set /p "Input=> Select a Browser: "
if not defined Input goto Input
set "Input=%Input:"=%"
set "Count=1"
:: NOTE if the browser name is typed out and matching on the name then the last match will be chosen.
:: As it is currently setup this means that the 32-bit version will always win on a name match.
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet" 2^>nul') do (
    if /i "%Input%"=="%%~nA" set "Choice=%%~A"
    if "%Input%"=="!Count!" set "Choice=%%~A"
    set /a "Count+=1"
)
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet" 2^>nul') do (
    if /i "%Input%"=="%%~nA" set "Choice=%%~A"
    if "%Input%"=="!Count!" set "Choice=%%~A"
    set /a "Count+=1"
)
if not defined Choice goto Menu
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%A in ('reg query "%Choice%\shell\open\command" /ve 2^>nul') do set "Command=%%~B"
start "Browser" "%Command%"
endlocal
echo Done
pause>nul
```

Comment: on 64 bit machines the information is under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet` . However I'll edit my nswer

Comment: that's finding the browser, i need to select a browser and run them, how do i do that. can you suggest me how do i do it

Comment: yeah its working great but i don wanna manual input to select a browser. i need it to follow order of precedence. like if chrome is present then start chrome if not check for and start firefox if not both then i want to start default browser that would be internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

You'll need eventually  to start this as administrator because it exports values from the registry.I didn't use REG command for max compatibility:

```
@echo off
START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%.\BROW.reg" HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=4 delims=\" %%B in ('type %Temp%.\BROW.reg ^| findstr  /E  "HTML\shell]"') do (
 set "browser=%%B"
 echo !browser:~0,-4!
)
endlocal

del /Q /F "%Temp%.\BROW.reg"
```

**EDIT**

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions

echo.
echo.
echo INSTALLED BROWSERS
echo.
echo.

rem :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
rem :: exporting registry values for installed browsers
rem :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

rem for 64 bit systems
START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet
rem for 32 bit systems
if not exist "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet

setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" ^| findstr /E "DefaultIcon]"') do (
  rem extracting browser name from icon path
  set "browser=%%B"
  rem removing \DefaultIcon] string
  set "browser=!browser:\DefaultIcon]=!"
  rem get the browser name
  for %%P in ("!browser!") do echo %%~nP
)
endLocal

echo.
echo.
echo EXECUTABLES PATHS
echo.
echo.

setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=@=" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" ^| findstr /B "@" ^| findstr /E ".exe\\\",0\"^"') do (
  set "browser=%%~B"
  set "browser=!browser:\\=\!"
  echo !browser!

)
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=@=" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW3.reg" ^| findstr /B "@" ^| findstr /E ".exe,0\"^"') do (
  set "browser=%%~B"
  set "browser=!browser:\\=\!"
  set "browser=!browser:,0=!"
  echo !browser!

)
endLocal


rem delete temp file
del /Q /F "%Temp%\BROW3.reg"


echo.
echo.
echo DEFAULT BROWSER
echo.
echo.

START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW5.reg" HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=^" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW5.reg" ^| find "@"') do (
    set "default=%%B"
    rem removing double slashes
    set "default=!default:\\=\!"
    rem removing end slash
    set "default=!default:~0,-1!"
    rem get the name
    for %%D in ("!default!") do echo %%~nD
)
endLocal
del /Q /F "%Temp%\BROW5.reg"

echo.
echo.
echo DEFAULT .HTML VIEWER
echo.
echo.

START /W REGEDIT /E "%Temp%\BROW6.reg" HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f tokens^=3^ delims^=^" %%B in ('type "%Temp%\BROW6.reg" ^| find "@"') do (
    set "default=%%B"
    set "default=!default:\\=\!"
    set "default=!default:~0,-1!"
    for %%D in ("!default!") do echo %%~nD
)
endLocal
del /Q /F "%Temp%\BROW6.reg"
echo.
echo.
pause
```

Comment: thanx guys but I need to run the bat file in xp windows 7 and 8 aswell. is there a way to unify with minimal code and without hard Coding

Comment: also guys i could use comments in code, i am not so gud at coding and it hard for me to determine what each step is meant to do, so thanx i appreciate ur help

Comment: will it be possible to check for error level and run browser, i work with 3 or 4 browser. lets say "start BROWSER1.exe" if its installed it will run else check error level "start BROWSER 2.exe"

Comment: This is tested on windows Vista , XP and partially on Win 8.Should run everywhere , but better check and tell me if there are issues.I will add path to browser exes later.

Comment: how do we define relative path in it.? will it works in 64 bit and 32 bit machine without any mod.? i din find issue on 64 bit machnie it works for me. donno about 32 bit

Comment: Yes.It will work on 32 bit machine too.`if exist` checks are made for such cases.If the registry export is not successful for 64 bit machine it will try export suitable for 32 bit machines.

Comment: can you please add comments on the code describing the steps and thanx for ur quick response.

Comment: it gives me a couple of uninstalled browsers also since its not removed from registry. how do we solve that issue. also where do i add start command to run a browser from the list but i don wanna change the default browser

Comment: I've added a print of path to browser executables and also some comments.You can filter the executables with `browsers.bat | find ".exe"` .Also you can remove the `pause` at the end.

Comment: `for /f %%B in (call browsers.bat^| find ".exe") do start %%B some_link` . You must execute this line in another `.bat` file.Uninstalled browsers should not have an executable paths...

Comment: i couldn't get it to run from another .bat file should i be listing all browsers in separate bat file and then execute above line to find exe and start a browser from the list. will be helpful if u tell me what should be the contents of 2nd .bat file