# batch file for check firewall status and if disable start a file

Tags: batch-file, port, windows-firewall

I want a batch file that after running with standard access, checks the status of the firewall and if the firewall is disabled, start a file. But, if the firewall is enabled, show all allowed ports. Is this possible?

I am checking if the firewall is enabled or not by using the Windows registry value `EnableFirewall`.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile

I am not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: Use [how to read registry string value from batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3184738) and add a condition

Answer (score 1):

You can get the firewalls current state using this command:

`netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state`

You can also use the command

`netstat -ab | more`

This will get a list of all the open ports and display it on screen.

[image]

As for reading a registry key you can use reg query:

`reg query <KeyName> [{/v <ValueName> | /ve}] [/s] [/se <Separator>] [/f <Data>] [{/k | /d}] [/c] [/e] [/t <Type>] [/z]`

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742028.aspx