# Registry Query and Use Output in Post-Deploy Script?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, msbuild, registry

...using Windows 7...

I have a sqlserver.exe.config file that needs to get copied to the SQL Server BINN directory on my local machine (for the SQLExpress instance).

I can't assume the location, so I poked around in the registry and found

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLEXPRESS\Setup "sqlpath"
```

So in a CMD I would like to get the value of that and then copy the file to that place. The reason I need to do it in CMD is because this should be in a post-build event. Can anyone recommend how to do this with REG or anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got many solutions.

**1. You want to work in th old CMD fashion**

You can use REG.EXE command line program :

```
C:\silogix>reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fax" /v ArchiveFolder

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fax
    ArchiveFolder    REG_SZ    C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows NT\MSFax
```

Y'll fin in [an other article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script) how to split the response.

**2. With Powershell**

In PowerShell command line (or script) you can access the registry like a drive :

```
PS C:\silogix> (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fax").ArchiveFolder
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows NT\MSFax
```

It's shorter to write. Registry keys are items and values are properties. PowerShell is a powerfull command line interpreter (you can use for scripting) which is on the top of .NET Framework. It makes scripting easy for C# programmers.

JP

Comment: I like the PowerShell option. Then I googled all over the place trying to figure out how to get the PS output back into CMD so I can use it. Any ideas?

Comment: You can call your .PS1 file with th -F in your PS1 you can format your output with out-host, out-string or out-file.

Comment: powershell.exe -noprofile (Get-ItemProperty -Path "'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLEXPRESS\Setup'").SqlPath I am having a hard time trapping that with -F which I think is for numbers?