# How to retrieve only the user-variables part of PATH (excluding the system-variables part)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I would like to append a directory on to the end of the PATH user variable using `setx`.  Currently I have:

```
setx PATH %PATH%;C:\dir
```

Unfortunately this then inserts the entire contents of PATH, including the system variable part of "Path", into the user variable part.  For example:

```
System Variable "Path"

C:\A
C:\B

User Variable "PATH"

C:\X
C:\Y
```

would turn into

```
System Variable "Path"

C:\A
C:\B

User Variable "PATH"

C:\A
C:\B
C:\X
C:\Y
C:\dir
```

when I run `setx` the command above.

**Is there anyway I can avoid this duplication, and do a true "append" to PATH?**  What I want is:

```
System Variable "Path"

C:\A
C:\B

User Variable "PATH"

C:\X
C:\Y
C:\dir
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible using SETX, both are combined into the 1 PATH Variable

You will need to use registry such as

reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH

Comment: This was an acceptable alternative, though the full solution was somewhat messy in my opinion.  For others with the same problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script for a complete example of how to get the result of reg query in a form you can use to then set PATH with.