# Set variables in batch file with registry values

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I'm going To explain what I want because I really don't know how to get it done ...
In a batch file, I want to set some variables with registry values, for example,

```
\hklm\software\teste
    Test1   REG_SZ   c:\teste1
    Test2   REG_SZ   c:\teste2
    .....
```

And in the batch file

```
Test1=c:\test1
Test2=c:\test2
......
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script?

Comment: To one registry value I have it already, but to run for several, that's my problem ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for /f "tokens=1,3" %%a in ('reg query hklm\software\teste') do (
 set "%%~a=%%~b"
)
```

`echo/%valueName%`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That would work if the variables were in fact numerical sequence, but that was just and example, sorry. In fact the values are completely different, like, for example, name, address, telephone ...