# Loop Returns Unexpected Results

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, registrykey

I've written a batch file ([heavily influenced from answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script#)) that is supposed to loop through several key values and return the first instance where the value doesn't exist.

The issue is that I can't seem to get it to return the first instance of a non existent value; it either runs through the entire loop or it returns a value that actually does exist.

My code:

```
@echo OFF

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\OFFICE\15.0\Excel\Options"
REM set VALUE_NAME=OPEN

FOR %%V IN (OPEN OPEN1 OPEN2 OPEN3 OPEN4 OPEN5 OPEN6 OPEN7 OPEN8 OPEN9 OPEN10 OPEN11 OPEN12 OPEN13 OPEN14 OPEN15 OPEN16 OPEN17 OPEN18 OPEN19) DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %%V 2^>nul`) DO (
        set ValueName=%%A
        rem set ValueType=%%B
        rem set ValueValue=%%C
        if "%ValueName%"=="" (
            @echo %KEY_NAME%\%%V not found.
            PAUSE
            GOTO :ADD_KEY
        )
    )
)
CLS
echo loop finished
PAUSE
exit

:ADD_KEY
CLS
ECHO IT WORKED
PAUSE
```

In my tests, the above code returns the following:

```
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\OFFICE\15.0\Excel\Options"\OPEN not found
```

even though it does actually exist on my machine.

If I change the If statement criteria to `Not Defined ValueName`, it returns `loop finished`.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm probably missing something simple, but my Google searches have been fruitless.

Note: these values (OPEN,OPEN1,OPEN2,ect.) correspond to *enabled* Excel add-ins.

**EDIT**

So currently my machine has the value `OPEN`, but it does not have the value `OPEN1`. The goal here would be that upon finding a non-existent value (`OPEN1` in this case) the loop would be exited and the `ADD_KEY` section of code would be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you don't tell us what you expect and why you expect whatever that is.

Using your code, `ValueName` will initially have no value, so on the first loop, with `%%V` set to `OPEN` the `if` statement is evaluated as `if ""==""` since you haven't enabled `delayedexpansion` and you are using `%ValueName%`. Hence, you get the message `...OPEN`.

If you replace the `if` with the `if defined` version, then the fact that you get `loop finished` means that each of the items in your list (OPEN OPEN1...) **was** found.

We have no idea whether this is true on your machine. You can test this by deliberately deleting a key you are expecting to exist.

AAMOI, `set "ValueName=%%A"` is better syntax, since it makes the assigment immune to nasty invisible trailing spaces.

The `@echo` within the loop can safely be `echo`. All `@` before a command does is to suppress echoing of that command, hence the initial `@echo off` suppressses echoing, but needs to have itself suppressed.

And why use `if "%ValueName%"==""` when `if "%%A"==""` would accomplish the same thing without `delayedexpansion`?

Amendment

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %%V 2^>nul`) DO (
```

Will **not** execute the body of the `do` if the `reg query` returns no result.

Try

```
FOR %%V IN (OPEN OPEN1 OPEN2 OPEN3 OPEN4 OPEN5 OPEN6 OPEN7 OPEN8 OPEN9 OPEN10 OPEN11 OPEN12 OPEN13 OPEN14 OPEN15 OPEN16 OPEN17 OPEN18 OPEN19) DO (

 set "ValueName="

 FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %%V 2^>nul`) DO (
  set ValueName=%%A
  rem set ValueType=%%B
  rem set ValueValue=%%C

 )
 if not defined ValueName (
  echo %KEY_NAME%\%%V not found.
  PAUSE
  GOTO ADD_KEY
 )
)
```

That is, set `valuename` to *nothing*, use the inner `for` to set the value(s) required, if that fails (no output from `reg query`) then you've found a missing key.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, that was an oversight on my part. On my machine, OPEN exists, but no other OPEN values exist (i.e. OPEN1, OPEN2, etc.). So I want it to return the first non-existent value, in this case OPEN1. I have verified that OPEN exists and that OPEN1 does not.

Comment: You should `edit` this extra information into the question. It would appear that `%%A` or `Valuename` **is**  being set for an absent value. Perhaps displaying the value(s) found with `ECHO(%%A` would reveal why.

Comment: My question is updated. When I `Echo %%A` it prints `%A`, when I `Echo %ValueName%` it prints `ECHO is off`. I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: Brilliant! That works! Thank you both for your time and energy! Much appreciated!