# Get value from one in two registry entries via .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to .bat files. I have a registry entry, it should be in either
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\SpecialFolder` or in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\SpecialFolder`. I used the following code, though the registry entry is there this script returns text `oopsy`

```
@echo OFF

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\SpecialFolder"
set KEY_NAME_64="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\SpecialFolder"
set VALUE_NAME=PRODUCT_VERSION

FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B
    set ValueValue=%%C
)

if defined ValueName (
    @echo Value Name = %ValueName%
    @echo Value Type = %ValueType%
    @echo Value Value = %ValueValue%
) else (
    FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME_64% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
        set ValueName=%%A
        set ValueType=%%B
        set ValueValue=%%C
    )
    if defined ValueName (
        @echo Value Name = %ValueName%
        @echo Value Type = %ValueType%
        @echo Value Value = %ValueValue%
    ) else (
        @echo oopsy
    )
)
```

Comment: Well, you'll have a problem with delayed expansion if the value you're querying ever does exist, but that's not why you're getting `oopsy` I don't think.  Try removing `2^>nul` from your `reg query` statements to confirm, but I'm pretty sure the script is echoing `oopsy` because the values you're trying to query don't exist.  Also, after the first `@echo off` statement, you no longer need the `@` in your `echo` commands.

Comment: The [original code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/445323/5047996) works as there are no variables set and read like `%VAR%` in the same block `()` of code...