# Edit a registry entry & open the registry with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am using a batch file to update the registry & would like to open the registry at ***HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\RasMan\PPP\EAP\13*** to confirm the reg update was successful. The reg update executes but I can't get the registry to open at the specific path.
The registry path can open before or after the update.

---

REM --add the following to the top of your bat file--

```
@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------

echo off
start regedit
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\RasMan\PPP\EAP\13 /v TlsVersion /t REG_DWORD /d 0x000000c0

start regedit
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\RasMan\PPP\EAP\13

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only about checking if the modification was sucessful, you could also read the value and print it on the screen:

```
REG EXPORT HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\RasMan\PPP\EAP\13 someFile.reg
TYPE someFile.reg
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise. This seems to be a usable workarround

REG EXPORT HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\RasMan\PPP\EAP\13\TlsVersion /y test.txt
TYPE test.txt

start test.txt

Comment: Methods here as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script @David_D