# Need help getting the regkey entry value in script

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that will clean out temp files and all that but I need assistance getting a path from the registry into the script.  Specifically the Outlook temp file regkey entry.  I have the key path but I do not know how to grab the directory value from the registry and set it where I can then delete the temp files.  I probably do not make an since but I just started doing scripts and I guess I just suck lol.  I have done a reg query and it shows the path but obviously set /p name= or anything around that wont just set %name% as a path to where I could then do my delete script and *.*

Any help would be much appreciated!!!!!

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security"
set VALUE_NAME=OutlookTemp

pause

FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% ) DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B
    set ValueValue=%%C
)

pause

if defined ValueName (
    @echo Value Name = %ValueName%
    @echo Value Type = %ValueType%
    @echo Value Value = %ValueValue%
) else (
    @echo %KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
)

pause
```

This is something I have tried from another post but originally I was using this to make a file to the desktop and was going to parse the file for the temp directory then delete the files in the temp folder.  I also just paused it out to see what was working and what was not.

```
START /W REGEDIT /E C:\Users\"username"\Desktop "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security"
```

And that makes a reg file to the desktop and I tried finding on how to parse the file and found a post that used

```
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "KeyName" /v ValueName') DO SET Variable=%%B
```

But that didn't work for me or I am doing something incorrect.  Prolly just me but lol

Comment: A good start would be posting the registry key and associated values. _(an attempted script would be appreciated too)_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the value of a registry key from within a batch script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script)

Comment: Nobody here is omniscient.  The more information you can provide the better.

Comment: I have been reading that post and seems like he was just trying to hide an error.  I have however tried a lot of the scripts off that page and it is probably just me but it is telling me my path is not found.  But I can break it out and separate the Reg Query and it will find the path.  Not to mention I don't really know what the variables %%A, %%B, etc mean.  Google is not my specialty as I am not finding anything to helpful lol.  I will post what I have tried here.

Comment: @Compo Sorry for being such a newbie :/ lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following in your batch file then the location you require could be used as "%ValueData%"

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=2*" %%I IN ('REG QUERY "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security" /V OutlookSecureTempFolder') Do SET "ValueData=%%J"
```

You could then use the variable for your deletion thus:

```
DEL /S /Q "%ValueData%\*.*"
```

Comment: Still says, "The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value."  Does the value I make it after I query the key matter?  I changed it back to ValueName instead of OutlookTemp.  I was unsure if this set the key as a variable and would enable me to do something like this below to delete the files under this temp directory.
                   

del /q /f /s "%OutlookTemp%\*.*"

Comment: That is because you've provided us with the wrong name for the key value, you called it **OutlookTemp** when in fact it is called **OutlookSecureTempFolder**. I have fixed the answer above accordingly.

Comment: I thought when I was using /v I could set the variable to whatever >.<.  Now that I have this what do I use to deleted the files in the temp folder?  del /q /f /s "%J \ *.*"   or instead of %J valuedata?

Comment: Thank you for the help I really appreciate it!  I have now noticed that when I delete these files they go to the recycle bin.  Is there a syntax or something that I could use to make it permanently delete the files? I will try dropping /f off my del command and just use what you have here see if that does it.  Thank you again!!!!!

Comment: It still does not permanently delete the files and just deletes them to the recycle bin.  It also does not delete files under the directory.

Comment: Please note that marking answers as correct helps the site and motivates those who give their time to continue to do so. The new deletion question forms part of your overall script which should be posted as a new question and answered accordingly.