# Strip CMD output to just show directories

Tags: powershell, cmd, registry

I'm currently trying to replace a powershell script with a cmd script as it's more suitable for what is trying to be done.

In Powershell I'm using this bit of code to return a list of personal folder directories on the computer

```
$Name = [Environment]::UserName
get-item HKCU:\software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog - ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -expandProperty property | Out-File Z:\global\pst\PowershellOutput\$Name.txt -append
```

This does what I want and outputs a list of directories like so

```
H:\PST\My Outlook Data File 1.pst
H:\PST\My Outlook Data File 2.pst
C:\PST\My Outlook Data File 3.pst
```

However when I run this line to extract the registry key

```
regedit.exe /e Z:\global\battest\%username%.txt "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog"
```

I get an output with lots of unnecessary data

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog]
"H:\\PST\\My Outlook Data File 1.pst"=hex:0c,01,00,00,00,00,00,00
"H:\\PST\\My Outlook Data File 2.pst"=hex:f8,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"C:\\PST\\My Outlook Data File 3.pst"=hex:ac,02,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

This data is passed onto another program* so a work-around could be to use data within the "" marks however it also has the double backslashes which makes the data awkward to pass on.

Is there a better way to grab these values within CMD or perhaps a parameter which I've missed which just shows the directories?

- -Sorry for not including this before however this program is not a CMD program, it's visual basic

Comment: The problem with `regedit` is it generates Unicode text files per default, which are not trivial to handle by `cmd`; so use the `reg query` command instead...

Comment: Hi, may I ask why cmd is _more suitable for what is trying to be done_ than Powershell here ?

Comment: @sodawillow If I were to use cmd instead of powershell then no group policy changes will have to be made for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't have Office installed to test, this should get the work done

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "HKCU=&H80000001"
    set "subKey=software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog"

    >> "Z:\global\pst\PowershellOutput\%username%.txt" (
        for /f "tokens=2 delims={" %%a in ('
            wmic 
                /NameSpace:\\root\default 
                Class StdRegProv 
                Call EnumValues 
                     hDefKey^="%HKCU%" 
                     sSubKeyName^="%subkey%"
            2^>nul 
            ^| find "sNames = {"
        ') do for %%b in (%%a) do (
            for /f delims^=^" %%c in ("%%~b") do echo(%%~fc
        )
    )
```

It uses `wmic` to retrieve the list of values defined under the indicated key and filter the output to only retrieve the line with the names of those values in the form `sNames = {"v1", "v2", "v3"}`.

The `{` is used to separate the start of the line from the list of values (`%%a`) , and this list is iterated (`%%b`) to get each value. The last element in the list includes an ending `}` that needs to be removed, this is handled by `%%c` using the quotes in the value as delimiters.

The equivalent vbs version could be

```vbs
Option Explicit

Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Const ForAppending = 8

Const SUB_KEY = "software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog"
Const OUTPUT_PATH = "Z:\global\pst\PowershellOutput"

Dim fso, shell
    Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim values
    Call GetObject( _ 
        "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv" _ 
    ).EnumValues( _ 
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER, SUB_KEY, values _ 
    )

Dim outputFile
    Set outputFile = fso.OpenTextFile( _ 
        fso.BuildPath( _ 
            OUTPUT_PATH, shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%")  & ".txt" _ 
        ) _ 
        , ForAppending _
        , True _
    )

Dim value    
    If Not IsNull(values) Then 
        For Each value In values
            Call outputFile.WriteLine(fso.GetAbsolutePathName( value ))
        Next 
    End If

    Call outputFile.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that code, I don't fully understand it however I understand enough to be able to get the output into a text file.  It still displays the '\\' within the directories however that is a result I can live with.

Comment: I'd just like to add onto this and say that to receive the output into a textfile all that's needed is a '>> -InsertDirectory' at the end of this line `for /f delims^=^" %%c in ("%%~b") do echo(%%c`

Comment: @J.Hodge, answer updated to include the redirection to output file, double bar removal and vbs version.

Comment: Wow, thank you for those changes.  That allowed me to simply plug that in place of the powershell script without extra changes.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to use the REG QUERY command. In a single bat file it would like like:

```
@echo OFF
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3" %%A in (`REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog"`) do (
 set ValueName=%%A
)
echo %ValueName% > Z:\global\battest\%username%.txt
```

Got this from [How can I get the value of a registry key from within a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script)

Comment: Okay, I tried to run your bit of code and it only gave me one result?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise enter would send a comment.. With some searching I came up with this `REG QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog /s | findstr /L ".pst"> \"Z:\global\battest\%username%.txt"` however I can't get that to work as it gives me an 'invalid directory'.  I'm not sure why your code (which I don't fully understand) only gives me the one result either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch code to get the list of *.pst **files** (not directories) which work independent on number of *.pst files and their file names as long as the file names end with `.pst`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%# in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog 2^>nul') do (
    set "RegData=%%#"
    set "DelData=!RegData:*.pst=!"
    if not "!DelData!" == "!RegData!" call :OutputFileName
)
endlocal
goto :EOF

:OutputFileName
set "RegData=!RegData:%DelData%=!"
echo !RegData:~4!
goto :EOF
```

*.pst files are Outlook Personal Storage files which are container files for emails, contacts, ...

The command **FOR** runs console application **REG** to query all values of registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog
```

The output on Windows Vista and later Windows versions is for the example:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog
    H:\PST\My Outlook Data File 1.pst    REG_SZ    whatever the
    H:\PST\My Outlook Data File 2.pst    REG_SZ    data value is
    C:\PST\My Outlook Data File 3.pst    REG_SZ    of each value
```

There is output the registry key and next the registry values each indented with 4 spaces and with 4 spaces between value name and value type and 4 spaces between value type and data value.

But on Windows XP the output is for the example:

```
! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search\Catalog
    H:\PST\My Outlook Data File 1.pst   REG_SZ  whatever the
    H:\PST\My Outlook Data File 2.pst   REG_SZ  data value is
    C:\PST\My Outlook Data File 3.pst   REG_SZ  of each value
```

So there are first two header lines before the registry key. The registry values are also indented with 4 spaces. But there are 1 or more tabs instead of spaces between the value name and the value type and there are also 1 or more tabs instead of spaces between value type and data value.

**Note:** I don't know if `REG_SZ` is the right registry value type. I don't have this registry key at all in my Windows registry and therefore just added the 3 registry values as string values with the dummy strings.

So the tricky part is how to get the registry value name containing also spaces to get just the name of the *.pst files independent on file name.

This is done by assigning each output line with the exception of first line because of `skip=1` to environment variable `RegData` and get next from this line everything after `.pst` assigned to environment variable `DelData`.

If the line contains `.pst` in any case at all resulting in value of `DelData` being not equal value of `RegData`, the subroutine `OutputFileName` is called for further processing and printing the file name of the *.pst file.

In the subroutine `OutputFileName` first the string right of *.pst file name is removed from `RegData` using a string substitution. Next *.pst file name is output without the 4 indent spaces at beginning.

If the number of indent spaces would not be always exactly 4 spaces, the line `echo !RegData:~4!` could be replaced by following code to work independent on number of indent spaces/tabs.

```
for /F "tokens=1*" %%I in ("%RegData%") do (
    if "%%J" == "" (
        echo %%I
    ) else (
        echo %%I %%J
    )
)
```

The usage of **REG** instead of **REGEDIT** has the advantage that no elevated privileges of an administrator is necessary for running this batch code.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Nothing is output if the registry key does not exist. The error message output to handle **STDERR** is suppressed here by redirecting it with `2^>nul` to device **NUL**. See the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for details. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character on parsing the **FOR** command line and being interpreted as redirection operator on execution of the **REG** command line by **FOR**.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer however I think this isn't what I wanted, I wasn't able to get the output I wanted however I was able to learn from what you wrote.