# How to use the location of current wallpaper in cmd

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, pipe

I want to copy the image currently set as wallpaper to another location. I can see using:
`REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperSource` provides me with the information of the image location, but how can I pipe this and use this location?

I have tried `set %foo=REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperSource` To save it as a variable. I do not understand what am I doing wrong (I am new to batch and very used to unix).

I can see how they iterated over parts of the output string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script) though I am getting `%%A was unexpected at this time.` for:

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperSource`) Do (@echo %%A : %%C)`
```

In general it is much better if I could somehow pipe this so I will not have the need to use a variable. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the value of a registry key from within a batch script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445167/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-registry-key-from-within-a-batch-script)

Comment: Your `set %foo=REG...` is a bash construct not possible in batch (but in powershell). Your `for /f` is OK when used inside a batch file - on the cmdline the for vars have to use only one percent sign. To what command do you want to pipe the result?

Answer (score 0):

The following command line picks up the data from the registry and pipes it into the `Find` command:

```dos
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %A In ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperSource') Do @Echo %~B|Find ":"
```

Just change the `Find` command to whatever you're intending to pipe the path to. Also be aware that the data `%~B` may contain spaces so it could be prudent, depending upon the requirements of whatever you are piping it to, to surround it in double quotes.