# Pipeline in CMD. Passing the output of first command as the first argument of the second command

Tags: cmd, pipeline

I want to pipeline to a `copy` operation. For example if we look at the command:

```
copy a.txt b.txt
```

I want to get "a.txt" from the former operation that is (as I have tried and failed):

```
echo a.txt| copy b.txt
```

I know this is not the correct syntax and I am failing (after a long google search) to understand what is the correct syntax to pass the output of the former command as the first argument of the second command.

How do I pipe this?

Comment: Cmd.exe has a poor implementation of piping compared with other scripting languages, and unfortunately this isn't an option. You need to show where `a.txt` is coming from so that we can provide an alternative solution.

Comment: I am actually trying to alter an answer I have received for [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44049702/how-to-use-the-location-of-current-wallpaper-in-cmd?noredirect=1#comment75126980_44049702). I want this all to happen in a batch file. Do you recommend another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apart from the fact replacing an image with a text file is a poor idea, this is all you need from the command line. *(There is no requirement for a pipe)*.

```dos
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %A In ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperSource') Do @Copy /Y "b.txt" "%~B">Nul
```

*I would guess that you'll need to change `"b.txt"` accordingly.*

**Edit**

Your updated command from a batch file:

```dos
@Echo Off
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    'REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General"^
 /V WallpaperSource') Do Copy /Y "%%~B" "backup%%~xB">Nul
```

Comment: I was aiming for `For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %A In ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Desktop\General" /v WallpaperSource') Do @Copy /Y "%~B" backup.jpg` :). Thanks a lot though, you really helped.

Comment: Your whole concept of using a pipe was wrong then, hence the reason I thought you wanted to overwrite the in place wallpaper image. As your initial post mentions a batch file, I have edited my answer to properly answer the question according to the now known goal.